# How to flat a pandas series of json string into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
            date_hour                                            content
0 2016-10-17 00:00:00  [{"81": 0.0, "82": 0.0, "83": 0.0}]
1 2016-10-17 01:00:00  [{"81": 0.0, "82": 0.0, "83": 0.0}]
```

I want to flat the df.content into a dataframe like this

```
                        81     82  83  
2016-10-17 00:00:00      0      0   0
2016-10-17 01:00:00      0      0   0
```

how can I achieve this?

I tried:

```
# work for one item, though I can concat them, but it's slow(I have each json of 7k k/v pairs), took 2.5s for each
pd.read_json(df.head(1).content.item(), orient='records')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `str[0]` to grab first element

```
pd.DataFrame(df.content.str[0].tolist()).set_index(df.date_hour)

                      81   82   83
date_hour                         
2016-10-17 00:00:00  0.0  0.0  0.0
2016-10-17 01:00:00  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pd.Series in the `apply` function to convert dictionaries in a Series object to columns, and then use `pd.concat` method to bind the `date_hour` column with the expanded data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([df.date_hour, df.content.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]))], axis=1)

#             date_hour  81  82  83
#0  2016-10-17 00:00:00 0.0 0.0 0.0
#1  2016-10-17 01:00:00 0.0 0.0 0.0
```